# How do I execute a logic on a different machine in the same or different network logged in as different user in AutoIt?

Tags: service, automation, autoit

I have this code in AutoIt that I want to work for a different machine on same or different network logged in as a different user without having to explicitly go to the machine and do it. I'd like to operate from my local desktop. The trouble is how do I automate authentication without any GUI?

```
 ;Global $machine="computer1"
Func _populate()
   Global $machine="computer2"
    Global $Services = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\" & $machine & "\root\cimv2")
    Global $ServicesList = $Services.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")
    If IsObj($ServicesList) then
        _GUICtrlListView_BeginUpdate($ListView1)
        _GUICtrlListView_BeginUpdate($ListView2)
        _GUICtrlListView_DeleteAllItems($ListView1)
        _GUICtrlListView_DeleteAllItems($ListView2)
        For $Services in $ServicesList
            if $Services.State = "Running" Then
               GUICtrlCreateListViewItem( $Services.DisplayName & "|" & $Services.Name & "|" & $Services.State , $ListView1)
            Else
               GUICtrlCreateListViewItem( $Services.DisplayName & "|" & $Services.Name & "|" & $Services.State , $ListView2)
            EndIf
         Next
         _GUICtrlListView_EndUpdate($ListView1)
        _GUICtrlListView_EndUpdate($ListView2)
    EndIf
 EndFunc
```

Machine named "computer1" is my local machine. I'd like it to work for "computer2" which is not my local machine. Also, if I do not comment this statement

`;Global $machine="computer1"`

,the logic doesn't work which I don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Global $Services = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
```

The `.` is a shortcut to the local machine.

Comment: That does not work if I want it for a remote system.